# Strategy for Getting SQL for AutomaticMigrations

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We're using EF 5RC, code first with migrations.  I feel like this should be an easy question to answer (i hope).  Is there a good way to figure out what the automatic migration is attempting to do.

I've added a migration through the Add-Migration PS command.
I've invoked Update-Database and all seems fine with that migration.
Now - I'm just running Update-Database like i normally do, but with the following error:

```
PM> update-database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Web'.
Using NuGet project 'DataAccess'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'UserGroup' (DataSource: (localdb)\v11.0, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending code-based migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201206301526422_AutomaticMigration.
Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.
```

Notice, i'm adding the -Verbose option, and I've tried it again with the -Script.  But I have no idea what we're migrating to; and what SQL - or what it thinks will result in data loss.

I do not want to simply enable "allow data loss" here, but am trying to understand how to troubleshoot these migrations.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just run:

```
PM> Update-Database -Script -Force
```

This will generate the SQL and display it in a window without running it.

Comment: If I enable allowing data loss, can it erase all my rows? I added the `MaxLength` attribute to a column, I I know none of the rows in the DB actually exceed that length, if one does I don't mind to be truncated. So this is what data loss means, or it will literally remove all the rows from DB?

Comment: @Shimmy it won't erase your rows.

Comment: But it can drop or shorten columns

Answer (score 9):

I got this error on Azure after a publish , but there u cant use -Force , so global solution (and no need for -Force on local too )

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // <-- THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: just to add this goes inside your configuration class constructor, which inherits from DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourDataContext> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829093(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I got stuck with the Azure post publish issue

Comment: Pretty dangerous to allow data loss via a migration in a production environment.